# Should I use explode, split, and/or trim; and how?

Tags: php, google-maps, trim, explode

I'd like to get some values out of this:

```
$bounds = '((-34.41859810454894, 150.5594567718506), (-34.375112955999064, 150.74124617004395))';
```

My goal is to list each of the four numbers as its own variable:

```
$swla = -34.41859810454894;
$swlo = 150.5594567718506;
$nela = -34.375112955999064;
$nelo = 150.74124617004395;
```

Here's my crappy hack attempt:

```
$pieces = explode("),", $bounds);
var_dump($pieces); //array(2) { [0]=> string(39) "((-34.41859810454894, 150.5594567718506" [1]=> string(43) " (-34.375112955999064, 150.74124617004395))" } 
echo '<br />';

$sw = trim(substr($pieces[0], 2));
echo $sw .'<br />'; //-34.41859810454894, 150.5594567718506
$ne = trim(substr($pieces[1], 2), " ) ");
echo $ne.'<br />'; //-34.375112955999064, 150.74124617004395

$sw = explode(",", $sw);
var_dump($sw); //array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "-34.41859810454894" [1]=> string(18) " 150.5594567718506" } 
echo '<br />';
$ne = explode(",", $ne); //array(2) { [0]=> string(19) "-34.375112955999064" [1]=> string(19) " 150.74124617004395" } 
var_dump($ne);
echo '<br />';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest method is probably [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all):

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9.-]+/', $bounds, $matches);
list($swla, $swlo, $nela, $nelo) = $matches[0];
```

If you want floats, then you can use `sscanf`. However, these numbers are too precise to fit correctly in PHP doubles, you will lose some precision in doing so.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`sscanf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php)**:

```
sscanf($bounds, "((%f, %f), (%f, %f))", $swla, $swlo, $nela, $nelo);
```

That will convert your coordinates to `floats`. You can learn more about formats [here](http://php.net/sprintf).

Answer (score 2):

Just to show you can use sscanf()

```
$bounds = '((-34.41859810454894, 150.5594567718506), (-34.375112955999064, 150.74124617004395))';

sscanf($bounds,'((%[-0-9.], %[-0-9.]), (%[-0-9.], %[-0-9.]))',$swla,$swlo,$nela,$nelo);

echo $swla,PHP_EOL;
echo $swlo,PHP_EOL;
echo $nela,PHP_EOL;
echo $nelo,PHP_EOL;
```

gives

```
-34.41859810454894 
150.5594567718506 
-34.375112955999064 
150.74124617004395
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would have done this:-

```
$bounds = '((-34.41859810454894, 150.5594567718506), (-34.375112955999064, 150.74124617004395))';
$bounds = str_ireplace(array('(', ')'), '', $bounds);
$bounds = explode(',', $bounds);
foreach($bounds as $key => $bound){
    $bounds[$key] = floatval($bound);
}
var_dump($bounds);
```

Output:-

> array
>    0 => float -34.418598104549
>    1 => float 150.55945677185
>    2 => float -34.375112955999
>    3 => float 150.74124617004

I don't know how much precision you need, but this method does lose some.

Answer (score 0):

I like the preg_match version, but depending on your usage you can certainly use explode to load these into arrays as well.

```
 $bounds = '((-34.41859810454894, 150.5594567718506), (-34.375112955999064, 150.74124617004395))';
 $tempArray = explode(',', $bounds); 

 //Gives you $tempArray[0] = ((-34.41859810454894
 //and $tempArray[1] =  150.5594567718506)
 //and $tempArray[2] = (-34.375112955999064
 //and $tempArray[3] =  150.74124617004395))

 $latLongArray = array();
 foreach($tempArray as $latLong)
 {
     $tempValue = str_replace('(', '', $tempValue);
     $tempValue = str_replace(')', '', $tempValue);
     $latLongArray[] = trim($tempValue);
 }
```

You could then either push out LatLong array into an associative array with your variable names/etc.  It's really just a matter of whether or not you want to use regular expressions or how strongly templated your inputs are.